# How to integrate Google, Facebook & Linkedin login with nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new for Nuxt.js and i want to integrate login functionality with Google, Facebook, and Linkedin and also get basic user information like `name`, `email`, etc..

Comment: Did you read the documentation ?

Comment: @EncangCutbray Yes. I follow the instruction and getting access code but I didn't get user info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you retrive the accessToken from Facebook, you can fetch the Graph API endpoint such as `https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me?fields=id,name,email` .

You can check out [Facebook Dev Documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)